# How can the status code for a response provided by a @ExceptionHandler be set when the @Controller returns a reactive type (Mono)?

Tags: kotlin, spring-mvc, exception, reactive

How can the status code for a response provided by a @ExceptionHandler be set when the @Controller returns a reactive type (Mono)?

It seems that it is not possible via returning a ResponseEntity or annotating the @ExceptionHandler method with @ResponseStatus.

A fairly minimal test showing the issue (note that the response body and content type are correctly verified while the status code is OK when it should be INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR):

```kotlin
class SpringWebMvcWithReactiveResponseTypeExceptionHandlerCheckTest {

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/error-check", produces = ["text/plain;charset=UTF-8"])
    class ExceptionHandlerCheckController {

        @GetMapping("errorMono")
        fun getErrorMono(): Mono<String> {
            return Mono.error(Exception())
        }
    }

    @ControllerAdvice
    class ErrorHandler : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {

        @ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        fun handleException(ex: Exception): ResponseEntity<*> = ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON)
            .body(mapOf("key" to "value"))
    }

    val mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(ExceptionHandlerCheckController())
        .setControllerAdvice(ErrorHandler())
        .build()

    @Test
    fun `getErrorMono returns HTTP Status OK instead of the one set by an ExceptionHandler`() {
        mockMvc.get("/error-check/errorMono")
//            .andExpect { status { isInternalServerError() } }
            .andExpect { status { isOk() } }
            .asyncDispatch()
            .andExpect {
                content {
                    contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_VALUE)
                    json("""
                    {
                      "key": "value"
                    }
                    """,strict = true
                    )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

(build.gradle.kts excerpt showing relevant dependencies):

```
plugins: {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.5"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `.andExpect { status ...` has to be called after `.asyncDispatch()` (as was done with content type and body). It seems that the http status is updated. Possibly this is actually part of http standard for async requests, but I suspect this is a bug of the underlying MockHttpServletResponse.